# Pairing n things into n/2 pairs where order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics

How would I order n things into n/2 pairs when order doesn't matter?

I was thinking that I could do

$$\frac{{n\choose 2} {n - 1 \choose 2} \dots {2 \choose 2}}{2^n}$$

But I'm not quite sure. Any tips on seeing a pattern when doing this, and if my formula is correct?

Comment: I think the division by $2^n$ is already covered by using the choose if it is because the pair can come in either order.  You still need to worry about ordering the pairs.  Also, having chosen the first two in your ${n \choose 2}$, there are only $n-2$ items left.  You are only reordering $\frac n2$ pairs

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2m$. Line up the $2m$ people, in order of student number.

The first person in the list can be paired with $2m-1$ people.  For every choice, the first unpaired person in the list can then be paired with anyone of $2m-3$ people. for every choice, the first unpaired person in the list can be paired with $2m-5$ people. And so on.

Thus the total number of pairings is
$$(2m-1)(2m-3)(2m-5)\cdots (3)(1).\tag{1}$$
We can get a nicer closed from by multiplying top and bottom by $(2m)(2m-2)(2m-4)\cdots(2)$, that is, by $2^m m!$. We get
$$\frac{(2m)!}{2^m m!}.\tag{2}$$
There are a number of other ways to get Expression (2). For example, we count the number of permutations of the $2m$ people in two different ways.

The number of permutations is of course $(2m)!$.

Let $Q$ be the number of ways to divide our people into pairs. Then the (unordered) pairs can be lined up in $m!$ ways. For every such way, the individuals in the pairs can be permuted in $2^m$ ways. Thus the number of permutations of our $2m$ people is $Qm!2^m$. It follows that $(2m)!=Qm!2^m$, from which  Expression (2) follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Think of putting all of them in a line, which you can do in ??? ways.  Then split them into pairs-the first two are the first pair, the third and fourth are the second pair, etc.  How many different orders can give the same set of pairs?  You can reorder the items in some of the pairs, and you can reorder the pairs, so ???

Comment: wouldn't re-ordering the pairs be the same number of pairs?

Comment: The order 123456 gives the same pairs as 345612.  We need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

The cases

$A=\{(1,2),\,(3,4),\,(5,6),\,\dots\},\,B=\{(1,2),\,(5,6),\,(3,4),\,\dots\},\,C=\{(5,6),\,(1,2),\,(3,4),\,\dots\},\, \dots$ are the same and thus there are $\Large(\frac{n}{2})!$ cases that are identical. Hence the answer

$$\Large\frac{{n\choose 2} {n - 2\choose 2} \cdots {2 \choose 2}}{(\frac{n}{2})!}$$

which simplifies to

$$\Large\frac{n!}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot(\frac{n}{2})!}$$